# Meteors template - how to change the data scope?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, renderpartial, mustache

There is something I do not get with Meteor's template engine, being used with Mustache I can change the scope of the json data souce simply by enclosing the code with a {{#newscope}}{{/newscope}. In practice this does not seems to work the same way with the handlebars

Here is my template data source

```
   Template.aName.data = function()
     {
         return {"foo":"bar"};
     };
```

Then here is my html template (partial)

```
<template name="aName">
    {{data.foo}} // This prints "bar"

    {{#data}}
    {{foo}} // This does not prints anything but [object Object] (I expected "bar")
    {{/data}}

    {{#data.foo}}
    {{.}} // This prints "bar" but oh so ugly…
    {{/data.foo}}
</template>
```

What's the point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `with` keyword to change the scope

```
<template name="aName">
    {{#with data}}
    {{foo}} // prints "bar" as expected
    {{/with}}
</template>
```